# Can you make the "new answer" notification more obvious?

Tags: feature-request, answers, notifications

Today I answered a question. When I was writing the answer, I can see that only one very low-quality answer was there. So I thought, ok, let me answer this question!

After writing the answer and posting it, I see that suddenly there are two more answers which are very good and definitely better than mine. (although not a duplicate of mine)

When I was writing my answer, I don't think I noticed the notification saying that there are x new answers. It was placed right on top of the first answer, which is out of my view.

So I suggest that we change the new answer notification to be placed on the top of the screen. Just like the "This question is closed, no more answer will be accepted" notification. And make it a brighter color so that everyone notices it.

This way, we can avoid posting duplicate answers and waste our time.

Comment: I agree that it should be shown from the top of the screen instead - but I think orange is bright enough and fits with the site theme

Comment: Write faster ;)

Comment: Isn't there the orange bar on top of the page already?

Comment: No, the orange bar only appears when the question is closed, not when a new answer is posted. @DeepSpace

Comment: @Sweeper I can swear that I get an orange bar on the top of the page when I'm writing an answer, saying that "There are X new answers to this question", although oddly enough it doesn't appear all the time. It's not really on the "top of the page", but it's right under the bookmarks bar of your browser.

Comment: @Sweeper if no official patch comes in, you could always [request](http://stackapps.com/)/write a greasemonkey script to do this for you.

Comment: I agree that it's very annoying. You can tell that there's activity on the page somewhere because the page is shifted downwards, but you have to scroll back up to know if it's an edit, comment, or answer.

Comment: @Laurel yes! That's exactly the flaw of the current system. When I am testing the OP's code in another window, I can't see the page shifted down!

Comment: I support this proposal as the same has happened to me many times: I write an answer, submit it and only then see that there are more answers, maybe better than mine; once I even discovered that there was already an accepted answer when I submitted mine, that was frustrating.

Comment: I think it's a good idea although I usually continue writing. My experience so far is that the existence of (other) answers is not equivalent to the existence of really good answers. If I've been writing for ten minutes then I usually don't throw it all away. Personally, I prefer reading the other answers afterwards to see whether (in my opinion) they are much better than mine. If yes, I often upvote and delete my own answer. No "imaginary internet points", but learned something new - all in all a win-win situation :)  IMO writers should be able to decide so it's good to keep them informed.

Comment: Okay, okay, here's a compromise we can all agree on: a pop-up window! :-)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, I like this premise.

I have proposed a solution to this before on Meta Stack Exchange, but there is far less traffic there so no one really noticed.

**Ajax load events on question pages should cause a counter to increase as a prefix to the title of the page so you can detect changes if in another tab.**

I discuss it more here [Help reduce rubbernecking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246404/178816)

It could look like this:

[image]

I don't think it would take too much alteration to accomplish, although it would be a small undertaking. In the linked MSE post I tried to identify the area of code where the hook for the counter could be placed.

Comment: I honestly wouldn't notice a change in the tab, especially considering I can't see much more than the favicon anyway, due to the number of tabs open. I'd prefer an orange or yellow `position: absolute;` banner appear on the screen saying hey, a new answer has been posted.

Comment: @TylerH Don't you mean `position: fixed`?

Comment: @SeinopSys I meant `position: absolute;`, but either one would work fine as long as they're placed in the right location to be noticed.

Comment: I think `postion: fixed` is way better because I don't need to scroll up to see it. @TylerH

Comment: @Sweeper Depending on where it is placed you wouldn't need to scroll up to see it with `position: absolute;`, either.

Comment: Absolute means you can only place it for a screensworth of text. If the user scrolls past it, it's gone. Fixed is the clear winner.

Comment: Aside from a sloppy implementation using a guessed offset with position:absolute, smashing a bright banner into the page isn't going to be any different than the current banner. position:fixed would be the way to go there, so that when you are actually scrolled down the page answering, it shows up - however, it makes little difference. The point of this answer is to highlight changes to pages while *not* actively interacting with them. Once answering there is not a need to view another answer in my opinion so much as it is nice to see if there has been changes to an already open tab.

Comment: Make it play a beep

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, I have to play Devil's advocate and ask: what is the real problem here? From my perspective, having lots of answers to a question is a *good* thing. Even if yours doesn't end up as the "best", it may still contain something helpful to the OP or even some future user who stumbles upon the question. In other words, the fact that other answers were posted while you were crafting yours does not detract from the value of your answer.

If however, it's all about rep, and you were after some low-hanging fruit, that ended up being snatched before you could get to it, then, I can understand the conundrum. However, that's not the goal of StackOverflow. The idea is to help people. Rep is a measure of how must trust the community places in an individual; it's not a prize.

Long and short, I see little need for any sort of change. I think a bolder, more in-your-face notification would more likely than not discourage people from adding additional answers, even if they have a unique take or perhaps even the better answer. The current notification is sufficient for what it's intended to do.

Comment: The problem is people don't want to run the risk of posting the same answer as someone else a few seconds (or minutes) later and seem like they're just copying content. *And/Or* they care about being first; rep isn't the goal of Stack Overflow *the site*, but it's the goal of Stack Overflow *the community*, since it's the metric around which user interaction is entirely driven by the system.

Comment: What if the answer that I'm writing is a duplicate of the new one? Sure, I can delete it afterwards, but that will count as one of my low quality posts. I might get post banned if I encounter this situation often.

Comment: @Sweeper when multiple similar answers get posted at the same time, then this post does apply: you're answering "low-hanging fruit questions", and should better spend more effort into either finding a duplicate to flag it with, or another question to answer altogether.

Comment: The real issue, for me, is that time spent answering a question that's already been answered is time that I could have spent answering other questions.

Comment: "I think a bolder, more in-your-face notification would more likely than not discourage people from adding additional answers, even if they have a unique take or perhaps even the better answer." I don't think this describes the problem OP is actually trying to solve. I myself would like a better notification so that I can see whether or not the answer I'm writing is different or better than ones that have already been posted. If it is, I'll continue writing it, adding to the value of the answers. If not, I'll move on to another question where I can add some value.

Comment: With regards to changing the on page notification (and not the title for the tab which I cover in my answer) - I agree with you. There isn't really a need to change the on page notification, it is easy to get to, and to be honest sometimes I feel users will take that as an opportunity to plagiarize in the small time window. Creating a quality answer should certainly not conflict with someone else posting an answer in the mean time.

Comment: "that will count as one of my low quality posts" - really?? I can't believe deleting a zero-scored answer is a bad thing. Lots of downvotes and flags, yes, but otherwise it can't count against you can it?

Comment: The obvious problem is "I do not want to waste my time." If a bolder, more in-my-face notification helps me notice that someone else already said what I wanted to say (more or less), then I can stop what I am doing and go help someone else. That saves time; therefore, it must be valuable.

Comment: Also, here's a strawman argument, but maybe you can see the point of it: Should we intentionally hide information from users in order to bait them into posting more answers? I certainly don't think so.